# Averaging eighths in Python

Tags: python, rational-numbers

I'm trying to output the average of a list of fractions formatted as eighths and given as a total. For my purposes, eighths must remain as eighths and never be reduced. I've managed to write some horrid code that achieves this in the ugliest possible way. Can someone help improve this? A major improvement would assign the correct value to a variable like `avg_sc_len`.

```
#Scenario #1:
#total_pages = 3 5/8
#scene_count = 2
#The correct average scene length is 1 6/8

#Scenario #2:    
#total_pages = 90 7/8
#scene_count = 145
#The correct average scene length is 5/8

avg_sc_len = total_pages / scene_count
whole_part = avg_sc_len.numerator // avg_sc_len.denominator
remainder_numerator = avg_sc_len.numerator % avg_sc_len.denominator
remainder_fraction = Fraction(remainder_numerator, avg_sc_len.denominator)
scale_to_eighths = remainder_fraction.numerator * (8 / remainder_fraction.denominator)
print("Average scene length: ", whole_part, round(scale_to_eighths), "/8")

# This outputs "Average scene length:  1 6 /8" for Scenario #1
# and "Average scene length:  0 5 /8" for Scenario #2
```

Answer (score 6):

Add functions and PEP484 type hints.

Add unit tests. You already have two cases - you just need to convert them into `assert`s.

Don't conflate formatting with calculation.

### Suggested

```
from fractions import Fraction
from numbers import Real


def calculate_len(n_pages: Real, n_scenes: int) -> Fraction:
    return Fraction(round(n_pages/n_scenes * 8), 8)


def format_mixed(x: Fraction) -> str:
    whole, remain = divmod(*x.as_integer_ratio())
    remain *= 8//x.denominator
    return f'{whole} {remain}/8'


def test() -> None:
    # Scenario #1
    length = calculate_len(n_pages=3 + 5/8, n_scenes=2)
    assert length == 1 + Fraction(6, 8)
    assert format_mixed(length) == '1 6/8'

    # Scenario #2
    length = calculate_len(n_pages=90 + 7/8, n_scenes=145)
    assert length == Fraction(5, 8)
    assert format_mixed(length) == '0 5/8'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks excellent.

Comment: Later on, the asserts can easily be turned into unittests with pytest.